# willSelectRowAtIndexPath not changing detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method to change the `detailTextLabel` of the selected cell, i.e. i assign `\U0001F44D` to the  `detailTextLabel.text` of the selected cell and assign `@""` to the previously selected cell, the problem is that the previous cell is assigned `@""` but  `\U0001F44D` doesn't appear on the newly selected cell, the code is as follows:

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedCalcMethod inSection:0]; // index of previously selected cell

    [self.mainTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:index].detailTextLabel.text=@"";
    [self.mainTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].detailTextLabel.text =@"\U0001F44D";

return indexPath;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Never change any values inside the cell directly like that. Change your *model* (the underlying data) and then, after the selection has taken place (i.e. after the runloop has completed), call `reloadData` on the table so that the table *fetches* the correct new value by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in the usual way.

Comment: actually it's better to reload only 'dirty' index paths instead of the whole table

Comment: @kambala Well, you could call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, but if you don't want the animation you gain little by doing this, since even `reloadData` only reloads the data for the visible cells, of which there are very few, while on the other hand `reloadRows` has to recalculate just as much of the table layout as `reloadData`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use DidSelectRowAtIndexPath instead of WillSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{

    NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedCalcMethod inSection:0]; // index of previously selected cell

    [self.mainTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:index].detailTextLabel.text=@"";
    [self.mainTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].detailTextLabel.text =@"\U0001F44D";

    return indexPath;
}
```